# How to make turnover on Mysql database records

Tags: mysql

I am a website developer and I need help for an analyse: My (future) website is more or less a villa directory. People can add their villas there. Each villa will be stored in database.

I need to show 15 villas per page but I want a "turn over" (not sure it's the correct word in English) of the villas: every hour the villa that appears first on first page becomes the last villa of last page (so every villa rank increase of 1 except the first one that become the last). I want every villa to have the same chance (more or less) to appear on the first page. I don’t want a totally random system.

I need help on how to make a simple system that would not take a lot of resources (should be working with a few millions of records).

Note: I don’t want to use the ID of the villa because if a person posts 3 different villas at the same time, they will be all shown next to each other.

**My proposition:**
I create a field (INTEGER) called “random_order” for each villa and I put a random number between 0 and Max(INTEGER) and I create an Index on the column “random_order”.
Then to get the records in the order I want, I store (dunno where yet) a variable that point to a record in the index. Then every hours, I increase by 1 this variable (with a modulo).
I’m not an expert on indexes so I’m not really sure if it’s possible to do it and how to do it. I don’t know if there is a better way to do it as well…

Could you please tell me if this is correct or if you have better ideas?

Thank you

Comment: im just wondering why if you dont want a random system, you are creating a field called 'random order' ? what about a second index for display that gets rid of the problem of someone putting 3 things at a time. its better to put actual code here i think than theoretical stuff, but im no veteran. good luck with it.

Comment: Well I post my analyse of it so if my idea is stupid (and it seems to be the case as you propose me something better) then I don't spend time on something stupid... But if you prefer code, it would help me al lot if you could tell me how to make a second index that could fit my needs. Tks

Comment: Hey cigar, your comment is back! Please tell me more about your solution. I don't understand how to make an index with random positions. tks

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you could do, is store a count variable - from 0 to MAX, and constantly update that. Then query the server for the top 15 villas (using `ORDER BY ASC/DESC`) on  (random_order +  count). This will prevent the need to update the column every hour - only the count variable needs to be updated.

EDIT:

First you would get the count (from where you have stored it) and store it in a variable - count.
Then execute a query like

```
SELECT *, (random_order + <count>)%MAX_VAL AS villa_order 
FROM villa_table 
ORDER BY villa_order ASC
LIMIT 15
```

This will prevent constant unnecessary updations to your indexed column.

EDIT 2:

Ok after further analyzing, this is how i would do this. 
Execute a simple select query

```
SELECT * FROM villa_table 
WHERE random_order > count 
ORDER BY random_order
LIMIT 15
```

If the number of rows in the result set is < 15 then fill in the remaining records from the beginning using.

```
SELECT * 
FROM villa_table 
ORDER BY random_order ASC 
LIMIT <number of rows to be filled>
```

Even on 20m rows on an indexed column this takes < .5s.

Comment: I don't understand the difference with my proposition: you have a count variable (same as me) and an index on "random_order + count". I don't understand how you can put an index on "random_order + count" as "random_order" is a column and "count" is a single variable.

Comment: There's not index on "random_order + count". There is a single index on random_order. The count is just added to it in the query, so the whole list doesn't have to be updated constantly.

Comment: Your code is working only in the case that the random_order column has value that are unique and different by 1 only and starting from 0. So if i have {villaA:20 villaB:12 villaC:31} then it's not working...

Comment: mmm doesn't work as well but i get the idea: Need to add an other sql request before because my numbers are not consecutive. Something like "set value = (select random_order from villa_table limit count,1)" and then replace your "count" with this "value". It's a bit complicated but then I almost got what i want. I might have a better idea: I wanted to use 2 select with limits and with an union... The union is not working with 2 limites but it might if I store the results in temporary table. But not sure it will be efficient. I will try.

Comment: @viv Right, you would need to do that since your numbers aren't consecutive. It's a little complicated, but waaay faster than updating your index constantly.

Comment: Thanks a lot. What about doing a "select villa_id from villa_table order by random_order limit count, (totalNumberVilla - count)" then put this in a temporary table then add (if needed) the same but from 0 to count? it's more simple but not sure it's fast...

Comment: What would you gain by creating a temporary table, when you eventually need to display the data to the user on a webpage? It would be slower. And you would need to manually delete all the temporary tables, as they only get destroyed when the session closes.
Also, (just FYI) to update an indexed column over 20m rows takes about 17 mins.